# Most efficient way of applying a function based on condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose we have a master dictionary `master_dict = {"a": df1, "b": df2, "c": df3}`. Now suppose we have a list called `condition_list`. Suppose `func` is a function that returns a new dictionary that has the original keys of `master_dict` along with potentially new keys.

What is the best way to get the below code to work when the length of `condition_list` is greater than 2:

```
if(len(condition_list) == 1):
   df = master_dict[condition_list[0]] 
else:
   df = func(master_dict(condition_list[0]))
   df = df[condition_list[1]]
```

Comment: It's pretty unclear to me what you are trying to do here. Can you give a working example when the length of `condition _list` is 2 of what your desired results are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask clearly. Declare input and output. And try to make a demo code. Anyway, use a loop.

```
for i in range(len(condition_list)):
    if i==0: df = master_dict[condition_list[i]]
    else:    df = func(df)[condition_list[i]];
```

If the "df" is a dataframe of pandas, the conditions can be applied at once. Search "select dataframe with multiple conditions"